# How do I make scrapy work on Google Functions using Flask & Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, google-cloud-functions

Hiya I've been following this tutorial:
https://weautomate.org/articles/running-scrapy-spider-cloud-function/

I'm trying to get this web scraper to run in the cloud and be able to recieve post requests with the postcode which will cause a search of the post codes and return a list of addresses to the response.

Currently I just have this main.py file and requirements.txt file with scrapy and flask in it.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/start_scrape', methods=['POST'])
def start_scrape(request):
    postcode = request.get_json()['postcode']
    start_urls = [f'https://find-energy-certificate.service.gov.uk/find-a-certificate/search-by-postcode?postcode={postcode}']
    addresses = []

    class AddressesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'Addresses'
        allowed_domains = ['find-energy-certificate.service.gov.uk']
        start_urls = start_urls

        def parse(self, response):
            for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="govuk-table"]//tr'):
                address = row.xpath("normalize-space(.//a[@class='govuk-link']/text())").extract()[0].lower()
                address = address.rsplit(',', 2)[0]
                link = row.xpath('.//a[@class="govuk-link"]/@href').extract()
                details = row.xpath("normalize-space(.//td/following-sibling::td)").extract()

                item = {
                    'link': link,
                    'details': details,
                    'address': address
                }
                addresses.append(item)

    process = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess(settings={
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False
    })
    process.crawl(AddressesSpider)
    process.start()

    return jsonify(addresses)


def my_cloud_function(event, context):
    def script(queue):
        try:
            settings = scrapy.settings.Settings()
            settings.setdict({
                'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False
            })

            process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
            process.crawl(AddressesSpider)
            process.start()
            queue.put(None)
        except Exception as e:
            queue.put(e)

    queue = Queue()

    main_process = Process(target=script, args=(queue,))
    main_process.start()
    main_process.join()

    result = queue.get()
    if result is not None:
        raise result 

    return 'ok'
```

I'm getting a few errors from this script when it first launches but it does successfully compile:

TypeError: start_scrape() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
.view_func ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py:99 )
2
MissingTargetException: File /workspace/main.py is expected to contain a function named /start_scrape
.get_user_function ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/_function_registry.py:41 )
1
NameError: name 'start_urls' is not defined
.AddressesSpider ( /workspace/main.py:16 )
1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
. ( /workspace/main.py:3 )

When sending a curl post with -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{"postcode": "OX4+1EU"}'

I get a 500 error.  Any help to fix this issue would be great

I've been trying to run this scrapy, I was expecting it to return a list of addresses in a json format when sending a postcode. Currently it seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create the scrapy process, you perform a start and then you return the jsonify HTTP response.

Therefore, the scrapy process runs in backgrount -> That's your problem.

Indeed, with Cloud Functions (cloud run and AppEngine standard) you are charged only when the HTTP request is processed. Outside the request processing, because you are not charged, the CPU is throttled. After 15 minutes (with Cloud Run, I think it's 30 minutes with Cloud Functions 1st gen) without any request processing, the instance is offloaded

And so, you can't run anything (or very slowly) in background. If it's too slow, the instance is removed before the end of the scrap.

---

To solve that, you can use Cloud Run (or Cloud Functions 2nd generation, it's the same thing) with min instance option, or no CPU throttled option if the processing takes less than 15 minutes.

Of course, more CPU usage incurs additional fees!

Comment: Brilliant, something so simple has given me a few steps ahead, however the script doesn't want to receive post requests with the postcode attached at the moment, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know scrapy and how to solve that software issue. But, if you have an error 500 means that your request is accepted but your function crash. Issue is in the code not on the platform.